# Mounting PSGI app by regex - different paths -> one app

Tags: perl, psgi

Looking for a way, how to run the same `PSGI $app` for multiple requests what aren't defined by the `mount prefix`. How to `mount` in such screnario? E.g. let say i have in my `app.psgi`

```
use Plack::Builder;

my $defaultapp = sub { ... };
my $someapp = sub { ... };
my $otherapp = sub { ... };

builder {

    mount '/some' => $someapp;    # ok

    #and here need something like:
    mount "_regex_here" => $otherapp;   #???

    mount '/' => $defaultapp; #OK - last mount is the "default"
}
```

E.g., the requests matching

- `/some/path` - want be handled by the `$someapp` (this is OK)
- `/[A-Z]\w+/\w+\.(xxx|yyy|zzz)$` - want be handled by the `$otherapp`
- any other request want be handled by the `$defaultapp` (Ok too)

This is probably "damm-easy" - but my reading thru of the [Plack::Builder](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Builder) doesn't give the answer. (Each `mount` in the maual and examples are `strict /path` based...)

**EDIT**: If this isn't possible by the `mount` is it possible to solve the above requirement in some *clean* (read not hackish) way? I don't need change the `PATH_INFO`, nor the `SCRIPT_NAME` (as URLMap is doing) - just need run the given `$otherapp`, for the matched requests.

**EDIT2**:

To be more clear. The `$someapp` and the `$otherapp` are already existing applications. Especially the `$otherapp` is an complex application what handles every request on its own way - but the requests what "belongs" to the `$otherapp` is possible to describe by regex.

I can't use the `mount /fixed/prefix` because the `$otherapp` creates different urls at runtime, e.g. for example based on the users activity it could create `/Abc/xyz.eee` and/or `/Zzz/uuu.ddd` etc.. Therefore i can't prefix the `$otherapp` as for example:

```
mount '/other' => $otherapp
```

Now, want "import" this old-fashinoed `$otherapp` to an new PSGI based server and moreover, the `$defaultapp` and the `$someapp` will do something with the data of the `$otherapp`. It sounds complicated, but in the reality it isn't - only need run the `$otherapp` based on the requests regex, e.g. something as Apache's `SetHandler somehandler *.ext`...

Comment: How about proxy-application, that redirects to the another one by the URL?

Comment: I use Plack::Builder to mount several Dancer2 apps at different prefixes, e.g. `/foo` and `/bar`. Dancer2 has complex routing logic, including wildcard and regex matching, so that is where I handle variable routes. Perhaps you could do something similar in your apps?

Answer (score 0):

The [code](https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Plack-1.0034/lib/Plack/App/URLMap.pm#26) actually is

```
push @{$self->{_mapping}}, [ $host, $location, qr/^\Q$location\E/, $app ];
```

As you can see, no regex supported in `$location` <s>*but* maybe you can trick it by providing `'\\Eregex_here\\Q'` as a location</s> and I don't know the way to trick it.

Comment: Thanx - and exists some _clean_ (correct) way solve the above?

Comment: You can't cancel `\Q` by a value in the quoted variable.

Comment: Wow, never knew that. Fixed.